# How to refactor the following Rails erb code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I need to refactor this code by using link_to method.

```
 <a href="post.html">
       <h2 class="post-title">
                <%= post.title %>
       </h2>
       <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                <%= post.subheading %>
       </h3>
 </a>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 <%= link_to ".........",post) %>
```

The "......" will be the refactored code.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass a block to the `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to post_url(@post) do %>
  <h2 class="post-title">
    <%= post.title %>
  </h2>
  <h3 class="post-subtitle">
    <%= post.subheading %>
  </h3>
<% end %>
```